# Separate class for foreign key constraints?

Tags: c#, oop, class, business-objects

For an example object with fields

```
Books
-----
ID
AuthorID
Quantity
ISBN
PublisherID
```

The 2 foreign key constraints correspond to Author Name & Publisher Name from 2 other tables.

1. For viewing the said object in a listview, is it recommended to create 2 additional fields (AuthorName,PublisherName) inside the same class or to create a separate object with 2 fields and inherit other fields from the Books class ?
2. What is the standard to follow for such scenarios inside enterprise applications ?

Damien.

Answer (score 1):

I subscribe to the school of thought that you do not query an object model.

Your problem immediately evaporates :)

What *I* would do is use a simple query layer to return the data I need.  In fact, I prefer a denormalized query store and if *that* isn't possible I will try to denormalize the table I am querying when doing inserts/updates and as a last resort I will use a join.

You may want to take a look at CQRS.